Sum of the difference of the absolute value of two disjoint sets
Let $M$ be $M = \{1, 2, 3,..., 2n\}$, and $M_1 = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ and $M_2 = \{b1, b_2, ..., b_n\}$ subsets of M such that $a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_n$ and $b_1 > b_2 > ... > b_n$. If $M_1 \cup M_2 = M$ and $M_1 \cap M_2 = \emptyset$, prove that $|a_1 - b_1| + |a_2 - b_2| + ... +|a_n - b_n| = n^2$.
Suggestions: Use the fact that $\{x,y\} = \{\max\{x,y\}, \min\{x,y\}\}$ and that $|x-y| = \max\{x,y\}-\min\{x,y\}$.
Using the suggestion, I got to a point where I concluded that 1 $\leq |a_i - b_i| \leq 2n - 1$ for $i \in {1, 2, ..., n}$. Hence $n \leq \sum_1^n |a_i - b_i| \leq n \cdot (2n -1)$. But I don't know how to continue from here.

Welcome to MSE. In this forum you're expected to show some effort in order to get help. Edit your question to include your work on the problem to avoid your question to be downvoted and eventually closed.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there is Prove that the value of the expression $|a_1-b_1|+|a_2-b_2|+\dots+|a_n-b_n|$ does not depend on the coloring., where a comment links to Proizvolov's identity. There are also the AoPS threads ...

(cont.) subdivision of {1,2,..,2n}, Combinatoric, Differences between partition into monotonic sequences and Combo seems Easy but I cannot Get.

Here is a proof that does not use $\max,\min$ identities and is different to the proofs linked in the comments.
Note that we can view the problem as a string of $n$ $a$s and $n$ $b$s, for example, the string $s=aaababbb$ would correspond to $n=4$, $M_1 = \{1,2,3,5\}$, $M_2 = \{ 4, 6,7,8\}$. It should be clear that the two representations are equivalent. Let $a_k$ be the index of the $k$th $a$ in $s$, and let $b_k$ be the index of the ($n-k+1$)th $b$ (that is, counting from the right). In the above example, $a_3 = 3, b_4=4$. Note that $a_k$ is increasing as a function of $k$ and $b_k$ is decreasing.
The 'cost' of $s$ is given by $\sum_k|a_k-b_k|$; in the above example, we have a cost of $|1-8|+|2-7|+|3-6|+|5-4|=4^2$.
We will show that anywhere the pattern $ba$ occurs in $s$, it can be replaced by the pattern $ab$ and the cost remains the same. By repeatedly switching $ba$ for $ab$ (cf. bubble sort), we eventually end up with the string $a...ab...b$ which has a cost $\sum_{k=1}^n|(2n-k+1)-k|=n^2$.
To see why we can transpose the pattern $ba$, suppose the indices are $b_i, a_j$ (then $a_j=b_i+1$, of course). Let $s^*$ be the string $s$ with the two indices transposed, that is
$a^*_j = b_i$, $b^*_i=a_j$ and $a^*_k = a_k$ for all other indices.
If $i=j$, then $|a^*_i - b^*_i| = |a_i-b_i|$ and the cost is clearly the same.
If $i>j$, then we have $ b_i < a_j < a_i$ and $b_i< b_j$ (and hence $a_j < b_j$ since there are no intervening elements). Hence
$|a_i-b_i|+|a_j-b_j| = a_i-b_i + b_j-a_j$. Furthermore,
$|a^*_i-b^*_i|+|a^*_j-b^*_j| = |a_i-a_j|+|b_i-b_j| = a_i-a_j+b_j-b_i = a_i-b_i + b_j-a_j$ and so the cost is the same.
The case for $i<j$ is similar, mutatis mutandis.
